# How can change the window title position xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, window, title

Is it possible to change the position of the title in the window? By default it is placed at the left side of the window title bar. I want to move it towards the center.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WindowChrome is helpful as well.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2010/08/25/experiments-with-windowchrome.aspx has some useful information.

For e.g., here is a sample MainWindow.xaml that you can use as a starting point and refine further.

```
<Window x:Class="WindowChromeTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WindowChromeTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Name="_MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="-1" ResizeBorderThickness="4" CaptionHeight="40"/>
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <Window.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!-- Opacity of < 1.0 helps show the minimize, maximize and close buttons --> 
                <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="Wheat" Opacity="0.8">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <!-- System Menu -->
                        <Button Grid.Column="0"
                                WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"
                                Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.ShowSystemMenuCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=_MainWindow}">
                            <!-- Make sure there is a resource with name Icon in MainWindow -->
                            <Image 
                                Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Icon}"
                                WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"/>
                        </Button>

                        <!-- Window Title - Center Aligned -->
                        <TextBlock 
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            TextAlignment="Center" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Text="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />

                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <!-- This is the Window's main content area -->
                <!-- Top margin 44 = WindowChrome ResizeBorderThickness (4) + CaptionHeight(40) -->
                <!-- Bottom margin 1 is somewhat arbitrary -->
                <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="White" Opacity="0.5">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Template>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You'll see a window that looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your question is about WPF. (as this is not possible in winrt)

Basicly, you will have to set the `WindowStyle` to None and create your own custom window.

You can find a lot of information and examples via the following links:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948(v=vs.100).aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140267/Create-Custom-Windows-in-WPF-with-Ease

Within the custom window, you can position the title wherever you want.